# How do you translate, "Please take this (gift) as a token of my gratitude / appreciation"?

Tags: english-to-japanese

> Please take this as a token of my gratitude.

As an attempt, I have 「感謝を表現するのために、はいどうぞ！」(casual)
Is this correct? If so, is there a more literal yet still natural way to translate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like this question is more about gift-giving in Japanese culture. But since there's the question of proper language involved, I am going to give it an amateurish stab. Japanese gifting etiquette is fairly unique and different from other cultures.

One common thing people say in Japan when giving gifts is to describe the gift as commonplace or trivial, as a humble gesture.

> つまらないものですが。
> This is really nothing of value.

Some other options:

> 心ばかりですが。
> Just something trivial to represent my gratitude
>
> ほんの気持ちですが。
> Just a token of my gratitude
>
> ささやかなものですが。
> Just some thing trivial

If you want to mention the gift is a token of your appreciation for something the other party did for you in the past, you can say something like

> 先日は大変お世話になりました。
>
> 先日のお礼に気持ちばかりのつまらないものですが...

If you want it casual/informal

> この間のお礼に、これ、良かったら、どうぞ！